# EFCore 3 - Saving Item throw sql exception 'cannot update identity column'

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, sqlexception

i'm working on Entity Framework Core 3.0 in a .net Core 3.0
but when i trying to update this item (only this class, in a db first model) it gives me this error

Sql Exception. cannot update identity column 'IDNRR'

i just get an item from X table and then save it with context.Update command

Unit test with exception

```
var c = _dbContext.TblWoTaskExtServices.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Idnrr == 15273778);
_dbContext.Update(c);
_dbContext.SaveChanges(); -> execute this give me the sql exception
```

[image: Unit test with exception]

class definition

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TblWoTaskExtServices>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.ExternalServiceCode, e.IdWotask });

    entity.ToTable("tbl_WO_TASK_EXT_SERVICES");

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.Idnrr)
        .HasName("IX_tbl_WO_TASK_EXT_SERVICES")
        .IsUnique();

    entity.Property(e => e.ExternalServiceCode)
        .HasMaxLength(255)
        .IsUnicode(false);

    entity.Property(e => e.IdWotask).HasColumnName("IdWOTask");

    entity.Property(e => e.DateIns).HasColumnType("smalldatetime");

    entity.Property(e => e.DateMod).HasColumnType("smalldatetime");

    entity.Property(e => e.ExternalServiceDescription).HasColumnType("text");

    entity.Property(e => e.Idnrr)
        .HasColumnName("IDNRR")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    entity.Property(e => e.Notes).HasColumnType("text");

    entity.Property(e => e.TotalCost).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");

    entity.Property(e => e.TotalCostFinal).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.IdCompanyNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.TblWoTaskExtServices)
        .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Idnrr)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdCompany)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_tbl_WO_TASK_EXT_SERVICES_tbl_COMPANIES");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.IdCostClassNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.TblWoTaskExtServices)
        .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Idnrr)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdCostClass)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_tbl_WO_TASK_EXT_SERVICES_tbl_COST_CLASSES");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.IdCurrencyNavigation)
        .WithMany(p => p.TblWoTaskExtServices)
        .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Idnrr)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdCurrency)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_tbl_WO_TASK_EXT_SERVICES_tbl_Currencies");
    });
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as screenshots.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have scaffolded dbcontext from the existing database. If so, share database DDL and whole TblWoTaskExtServices definition.

Comment: SingleOrDefault method may return the default value if no match found; normally you check the returned value for the default one and branch processing logic. Also, you have not changed the returned entity but used ```DbContext.Update``` on it, which changed entity state to "Modified". I suggest simply changing the needed properties of the tracked entity and then call ```SaveChanges```.

Comment: @metacube correcr, i miss closing brace, sorry

Comment: @metacube singleOrDefault... it's just an example... i get an item and then i save it, i should not get an error on idnrr column

Comment: how about a null check before calling `Update(c)`?

Comment: @jalsh null reference is not the error i get

Answer (score 0):

Solved without use of Update() method

as @metacube suggest

> Also, you have not changed the returned entity but used DbContext.Update on it, which changed entity state to "Modified". I suggest simply changing the needed properties of the tracked entity and then call SaveChanges